# What does "sets of arbitrarily large measure" mean --- question about $L_p$ embeddings

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The following are the results from a wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Embeddings) about $L_p$ space:

> a. Let $0 ≤ p < q ≤ ∞$. $L_q(S, μ)$ is contained in $L_p(S, μ)$ iff $S$ does not contain sets of arbitrarily large measure;
>   b. Let $0 ≤ p < q ≤ ∞$. $L_p(S, μ)$ is contained in $L_q(S, μ)$ iff $S$ does not contain sets of arbitrarily small non-zero measure.

Here are my **questions**:

1. What does "sets of arbitrarily large measure" mean? Is "$S$ does not contain sets of arbitrarily large measure" *equivalent* to "$\mu(S)<+\infty$"?
2. What does "sets of arbitrarily small non-zero measure" mean?

---

[Added:]

There is a result in *Another note on the inclusion  $L^p(\mu) ⊂ L^q(\mu)$*(
by A. Villani, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 92 (1985), No. 7, 485–487):

> The following conditions on measure space are equivalent:

1. $\sup_{E\in{\mathscr A}_{\infty}}\mu(E)<+\infty$
2. $L^p(\mu)\subset L^q(\mu)$ for all $p,q\in(0,\infty)$ with $p>q$

where ${\mathscr A}_\infty=\{E\in\Sigma:\mu(E)<+\infty\}$.

This is similar with (a) but $p,q\in(0,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a [comment response to Jack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340695/what-does-sets-of-arbitrarily-large-measure-mean-question-about-l-p-embe/340700?noredirect=1#comment735847_340700), but I need the formatting given by MarkDown.

---

The problem is that the Wikipedia sentence is ambiguous: and in one way of reading it, the statement is incorrect. Wikipedia contains:

> Let $0\leq p\leq q\leq \infty$. $L^q(S,\mu)$ is contained in $L^p(S,\mu)$ iff $S$ does not contain sets of arbitrarily large measure.

A big spot where it is entirely unclear is whether the phrase "Let $0\leq \ldots$" is part of the "left-hand-side" of the "iff". The usage of a full stop `.` instead of a comma `,` would suggest that it is not.

Then if we interpret "does not contain..." as what you wrote in your question, that is $\mu(S) < \infty$, then the statement is false! Because as in [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340695/what-does-sets-of-arbitrarily-large-measure-mean-question-about-l-p-embe/340700?noredirect=1#comment735807_340700) there exists $p,q\in (0,\infty)$ and a measure space $(S,\mu)$ such that $\mu(S) = +\infty$ while the $L^p \subset L^q$ inclusion holds, contradicting the "only if" of the "iff".

If we interpret "does not contain..." as what Villani wrote, that is $\sup_{A_\infty} \mu(E) < +\infty$, it is clear that [we will have a problem with the endpoints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340695/what-does-sets-of-arbitrarily-large-measure-mean-question-about-l-p-embe/340700?noredirect=1#comment735820_340700). So *neither interpretation works*!

---

The only way to fix the statement is to *correctly place your quantifiers*. That is to say, you can write that

> Given a measure space $(S,\mu)$, the following two conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\mu(S) < \infty$
> 2. For every $0 < q \leq p \leq \infty$ the inclusion $L^p \subseteq L^q$ holds.

I do not include the endpoint $0$ as I do not know how you want to define the $L^0$ space when $\mu(S) = + \infty$. To show that $1\implies 2$ you just use Hölder/Jensen; to show that $2\implies 1$ just take the function $f\equiv 1$ which is in $L^\infty$. Integrating in any $L^p$ for $p <\infty$ tells you that $S$ has finite measure.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your patience. To sum up your final version of the correct statement, if one only consider $p,q\in(0,\infty)$ then one should take Villani's statement; if one wants $p,q\in(0,\infty]$, then yours should be used. Right? What's more, this answers another related [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/341692/9464) about difference between $\mu(X)<\infty$ and $\sup_{E\in{\mathscr A}_\infty}\mu(E)<\infty$.

Comment: BTW, what's more interesting in Villani's statement is that away from the end point $\infty$, that _one single inclusion_ $L^p \subset L^q$ for $p > q$ suffices to show the "not too large measure" conclusion. Similarly, a single inclusion of $L^\infty \subset L^p$ for finite $p$ will tell you that $\mu(S) < \infty$.

Answer (score 6):

Pick a positive number $r$. Does $S$ have sets with measure bigger than $r$? Deos $S$ have sets of measure smaller than $r$ but not zero?

If, for every value of $r$ you answered yes to the first question, $S$ contains sets of arbitrarily large measure.

If, for every value of $r$ you answered yes to the second question, $S$ contains sets of arbitrarily small, nonzero measure.

Comment: Thanks. According to your answer, can I say that "S does not contain sets of arbitrarily large measure" is equivalent to "$μ(S)<+∞$"? Do have an example for the space in b?

Comment: Yep. A simple example for $b$ is a measure where individual points are given positive measure, and the measure of a set is simply the sum of the measures of the points it contains. Another is to use a set with an ultrafilter for its measure. (measure 1 if the set is in the filter, 0 otherwise)

Comment: @Jack: don't think that the answer to your first question is positive. Let $S$ be the two point set $\{0,1\}$ and let $\mu(\{0\}) = 1$ and $\mu(\{1\}) = +\infty$. Then $L^p(\mu) = L^q(\mu) = \{f: f(1) = 0\}$ for $p,q\in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: Note however in the previous example any function $f:S \to \mathbb{R}$ is in $L^\infty$. The way the Wikipedia conditions are written is not the best.

Comment: @Willie, as I understan from your comment, can I say that "S does not contain sets of arbitrarily large measure" is the same thing as "$\sup_{E\in\mathscr{A}_{\infty}}\mu(E)<+\infty$"? But then, according to the paper I cited in the "added" part, one only has the result of $(0,\infty)$, not $[0,\infty]$ which is in the Wikipedia results.