# Is $\sup_{E\ \text{of finite measure}}\mu(E)<+\infty$ equivalent to $\mu(X)<+\infty$ in $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This relates to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/340695/9464) I posted.

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(X)<+\infty$. Then $\sup_{E\in{\mathcal A}_{\infty}}\mu(E)<+\infty$, where 
$
{\mathcal A}_{\infty}=\{A\in\Sigma:\mu(A)<+\infty\}.
$

My **question** is:

> Is there a measure space such that $\sup_{E\in{\mathcal A}_{\infty}}\mu(E)<+\infty$
>   *but* $\mu(X)=+\infty$?

Comment: Here is a definition http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semifinite ... a semifinite measure space has the property: if $\mu(E)=\infty$, then the supremum of the measures of all subsets of $E$ with finite measure is also $\infty$.

Comment: @GEdgar, So this would not contradict Davide's answer, right?

Comment: Right, Davide gives an example of a measure that is not semifinite.

Comment: @GEdgar: Fair enough. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can "cheat" taking $X:=\{a\}$ and $\mu(\{a\}):=+\infty$.

Comment: According to your answer, can I say that "S does not contain sets of arbitrarily large measure" is NOT equivalent to "μ(S)<+∞" where @Hurkl gave an opposite answer?